# Python pandas Reading specific values from HDF5 files using read_hdf and HDFStore.select

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

So I created hdf5 file with a simple dataset that looks like this

```
>>> pd.read_hdf('STORAGE2.h5', 'table')
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
```

Using this script

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from pandas.io.pytables import Term

store = pd.HDFStore('STORAGE2.h5')

df_tl = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list(range(5)), B=list(range(5))))

df_tl.to_hdf('STORAGE2.h5','table',append=True)
```

I know I can select columns using

```
x = pd.read_hdf('STORAGE2.h5', 'table',  columns=['A'])
```

or

```
x = store.select('table', where = 'columns=A')
```

How would I select all values in column 'A' that equals 3 or specific or indicies with strings in column 'A' like 'foo'? In pandas dataframes I would use `df[df["A"]==3]` or `df[df["A"]=='foo']`

Also does it make a difference in efficiency if I use `read_hdf()` or `store.select()`?

Comment: Have a read on the extensive docs on this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#querying-a-table; FYI, ``Term`` is an older < 0.13.0 way of doing this.

Comment: @Jeff Ok so I guess it is going to be deprecated so I removed it. Thanks!

Comment: no its compatible, just an 'older' syntax (and the new one is more natural), of course IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `data_columns=` (you can use `True` as well to make all columns searchable)

(FYI, the `mode='w'` will start the file over, and is just for my example)

```
In [50]: df_tl.to_hdf('STORAGE2.h5','table',append=True,mode='w',data_columns=['A'])

In [51]: pd.read_hdf('STORAGE2.h5','table',where='A>2')
Out[51]: 
   A  B
3  3  3
4  4  4
```

Comment: I see so if I do not append the data columns when I store it using `to_hdf` it would not work if I use `store['table2'] = df_tl` either. I am surprise pandas does not automate the `data_columns=True`.

Comment: I am guessing I cannot use  `store['table2'] = df_tl` unless I want to read the whole table and edit it in memory.

Comment: correct, that stores it in 'fixed' format. It depends on your goal. If you need appending/query, or have huge data, then use 'table'. That said, 'fixed' is faster for read/writing so for a set that isn't huge it works well.